# C# variable questions

Tags: c#, methods

I am working on a project, in C#, that needs to run a method based off of user input.  The user can enter either a integer or a string into a text box.  Is it possible to create an undeclared variable and if not, how do I go about using the right method for the user input?  I plan on creating two overloaded methods.

Comment: pass object, and then convert it to int or string inside method itself

Comment: dynamic types can be used for that
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object` as type for your param and then use `.GetType()` or `is` to perform type checking. There are other alternatives like `dynamic` but it's more common to use `dynamic` when you need to perform method calls on your object without having to cast it to its actual type

Anyway if you're reading from console, it will always be a string, so you can `int.TryParse()` on it.

```
public void DoStuff(string param) 
{
    int chosen;
    if(int.TryParse(param, out chosen) 
    {
        // is an int do stuff with chosen
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // it's not do stuff with param
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The user can enter either a integer or a string into a text box.

Seems simple to me then. You get the input from the textbox through the Text property which is always a string. So you need to check if the input can be parsed to an integer using TryParse. 
Personally I don't see why you need overloaded methods. Are the methods the same except for the type of the param? If not I would not choose to overload but just different ones with clear naming.